# Code to show data up to 14 days ago from today's date

Tags: sql, datediff

I'm fairly new to SQL and learning as I go along with reports I get asked for. I need some help writing a sql code for pulling back all data over last 3 years up to 14 days prior to today date and this changes every day. So if today is the 28th Nov I need to see all data in a column called LastValidatedDate 13th Nov then tomorrow when i refresh the data it will show me up to 14th Nov and so forth.

I'm presuming it's some sort of date diff but like i said i'm still learning so can appreciate your help. So i need to see number of orders that were last validated prior to 14 days from today's date.

I'm still learning so think I need to use a date diff either in the Select or the Where clause?

Comment: Hi what have you tried so far? As for my understanding, nearly all SQL Server have functions like `GETDATE()`, `DATEADD(.., .., ..)` and `DATEDIFF(.., .., ..)`. In your example it would be `WHERE LastValidatedDate < DATEADD(DAY, -14, GETDATE())`

Comment: Hi this has helped thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.